# How do I beat Endurance levels?

Tags: gemcraft-0

I have a lot of trouble with endurance. I usually go down around wave 50 on the early levels. How can I improve my strategy to reach the higher waves?

I keep upgrading my towers and the monsters die with ease, but it seems like all of a sudden the waves are really hard and my towers can't put a dent in their HP.

Some questions:

- Are prismatic gems worth it compared to bi-colored gems around wave 50ish?
- Can you give any tips on when/how often to manna pool, for example "x1 time per wave" ?
- Are many lower grade gems better than a few higher grade gems around this wave?
- Are level 7 and above grade gems worth it, damage and price wise?
- I notice that when I replay an endurance level, my exp doesn't go up?
- Any other tips you can give for mid(?)-game endurance levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact of the matter is that actually beating endurance is practically an impossibility. There are, I believe, 512 waves total, and the HP increases exponentially at a rate that is quicker than your damage will increase. And on top of that, the lag will be so awful with all of those monsters with a such a high hp and dozens of gems firing off hundreds of times a second you can literally count the frames.

But there are certainly a few strategies you can employ to get pretty far(though, being a mid-game player you're somewhat limited by your skills). Many of them can be found in [this forum](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/23-gemcraft-chapter-0?page=1), written by people with more experience than me. I'll go ahead and answer your specific questions, though.

**Are prismatic gems worth it compared to bi-colored gems around wave 50ish?**

Perhaps. It depends on the level and your mana farms. Keep in mind that prismatics aren't really worth it below grade 11 and as a midgame player your skills probably aren't leveled enough to make them very effective.

**Can you give any tips on when/how often to manna pool, for example "x1 time per wave" ?**

This is something you'll have to do largely by feel. Once you get a good mana farm set up, you'll be doing it far more than once per wave, but it's just something you'll have to learn.

**Are many lower grade gems better than a few higher grade gems around this wave?**

A few high level gems is better than a lot of low level gems at that stage of the game.

**Are level 7 and above grade gems worth it, damage and price wise?**

From what I've read, grade 11 is when it stops being worth it to combine gems of the same grade. Though with prismatics I believe it's around grade 13.

**I notice that when I replay an endurance level, my exp doesn't go up?**

You need to beat your previous endurance score for that level.

**Any other tips you can give for mid(?)-game endurance levels?**

- Anger, anger, anger. You need to anger waves starting almost immediately to start raking in the mana. Speaking of raking in the mana, make Red-Orange gem traps to farm mana. These two things are vital to getting far in endurance.
- Patience: Be prepared to spend days on a single endurance run if you get far enough. Yes, the lag gets that bad.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of great video tutorials, [this one by ulegh](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRae8OlCQw4&feature=related) is particularly good (and long!). In the end he gets to this kind of situation:

[image: Wow]